# Gemfire CACHING PROXY

Tags: ttl, gemfire, geode, caching-proxy

I am using CACHING_PROXY for a Client Gemfire region, and it looks like the Caching that happens on the client is not honoring the TTL set for the entry in the backing region on the Server. Is there a way to have the Caching Proxy honor the TTL for the entry on the backing server region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a CACHING_PROXY region, ideally, you would want to keep that upto date with all changes on the server. The mechanism to achieve that in Geode/GemFire is Register Interest, which will push all updates from the server to the client for some/all keys.

To use this feature, you will have to:
1. Enable subscriptions when you create the client

```
ClientCacheFactory ccf = new ClientCacheFactory();
ccf.setPoolSubscriptionEnabled(true);
```

2. Register interest on keys interested:

```
 myRegion.registerInterestRegex("*", InterestResultPolicy.NONE);
```

For more details, please see the [documentation](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/events/configure_client_server_event_messaging.html).

Comment: it seems that this setup can still have data out of sync. When server is bounced, and during the downtime, there is something changed in the client side, this change is in client local only and client does not reload from server unless explicit unregister and register

Comment: Hi @XiaweiZhang 
If the client is not persisting data locally, it will have to fetch the data from server, and then will keep up to date with changes on the server side.

If the client is persisting data locally, you can configure durable subscriptions, where the server will keep track of all the events that need to be sent to the client: http://geode.docs.pivotal.io/docs/developing/events/implementing_durable_client_server_messaging.html